# how do I restrict the text length in jsp?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to restrict the text length in jsp.

```
    <c:forEach var="result" items="${resultList }" varStatus="status" >
li>${result.mkType }</li>

</>
```

let say I want to restrict the ${result.mkType} 's length

Answer (score 3):

JSTL has a function called [fn:length()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_length.htm)

You can use this to limit the length of a string or collection size with an if test.

For example:

```
<c:forEach var="result" items="${resultList}" varStatus="status" >

  // below you test if the string variable length is greater(gt) than 4
  // If it is greater than 4, then the code below will show, else nothing.  

   <c:if test="${fn:length(result.mkType) gt 4}">
     <li>
     ${result.mkType}
     </li>
   </c:if>

</c:forEach>
```